# Construct array by sampling over every n'th element along last axis

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

Let `a` be some (not necessarily one-dimensional) NumPy array with `n * m` elements along its last axis. I wish to "split" this array along its last axis so that I take every `n`'th element starting from `0` up until `n`.

To be explicit let `a` have shape `(k, n * m)` then I wish to construct the array of shape `(n, k, m)`

```
np.array([a[:, i::n] for i in range(n)])
```

my problem is that though this indeed return the array that I seek, I still feel that there might be a more efficient and neat NumPy routine for this.

Cheers!

Comment: You cannot do that: Numpy does not support jagged arrays, that is, array containing arrays of different size (you can cheat with Numpy array containing Numpy array but this is not really a unique Numpy array, and it is very slow). The provided code fails with n=2, m=5 and k=3.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! The range was supposed stop at n and not m. The resulting array  should have shape (n, k, m). I've edited the original question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want, without loops.  I tested for 2D inputs, it may need some adjustments for more dimensions.

```
indexes = np.arange(0, a.size*n, n) + np.repeat(np.arange(n), a.size/n)
np.take(a, indexes, mode='wrap').reshape(n, a.shape[0], -1)
```

In my testing it is a bit slower than your original list solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to write a faster Numpy implementation. One efficient solution is to use **Numba** so to speed this up. That being said, the memory access pattern can be the main reason why the code is slow on relatively large matrices. As a result, one need to care about the iteration order so the accesses can be relatively **cache-friendly**. Moreover, for large arrays, it can be a good idea to use **multiple threads** so to better mitigate the overhead coming from the relatively-high memory latency (due to the memory access pattern). Here is an implementation:

```py
import numba as nb

# The first call is slower due to the build.
# Please consider specifying the signature of the function (ie. input types)
# to precompile the function ahead of time.
@nb.njit # Use nb.njit(parallel=True) for the parallel version
def compute(arr, n):
    k, m = arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1] // n
    assert arr.shape[1] == n * m

    out = np.empty((n, k, m), dtype=arr.dtype)

    # Use nb.prange for the parallel version
    for i2 in range(k):
        for i1 in range(n):
            outView = out[i1, i2]
            inView = a[i2]
            cur = i1
            for i3 in range(m):
                outView[i3] = inView[cur]
                cur += n

    return out
```

Here is the results on my machine with a i5-9600KF processor (6-cores) for `k=37`, `n=42`, `m=53` and `a.dtype=np.int32`:

```
John Zwinck's solution:    986.1 µs
Initial implementation:     91.7 µs
Sequential Numba:           62.9 µs
Parallel Numba:             14.7 µs
Optimal lower-bound:        ~7.0 µs
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken this does what you expect, and fast:

```
a.reshape(k, m, n).swapaxes(1, 2).swapaxes(0, 1)
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
k=5; n=3; m=4
a = np.arange(k*n*m).reshape(k, n*m)
a.reshape(k, m, n).swapaxes(1, 2).swapaxes(0, 1)
"""
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
       [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]])

is transformed into:

array([[[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
        [12, 15, 18, 21],
        [24, 27, 30, 33],
        [36, 39, 42, 45],
        [48, 51, 54, 57]],

       [[ 1,  4,  7, 10],
        [13, 16, 19, 22],
        [25, 28, 31, 34],
        [37, 40, 43, 46],
        [49, 52, 55, 58]],

       [[ 2,  5,  8, 11],
        [14, 17, 20, 23],
        [26, 29, 32, 35],
        [38, 41, 44, 47],
        [50, 53, 56, 59]]])
"""
```

Timing:

```
from time import time
k=37; n=42; m=53
a = np.arange(k*n*m).reshape(k, n*m)

start = time()
for _ in range(1_000_000):
    res = a.reshape(k, m, n).swapaxes(1, 2).swapaxes(0,1)
time() - start

# 0.95 s per 1 mil repetitions
```